# Why is Pyodide giving me a 'File is not a zip file' error when I try to install a .whl package using micropip?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyodide

I'm trying to import a .whl package using micropip into pyodide for use in an html file, but am getting an error about "must be a zip file"?

Based on the documentation of micropip [here](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/loading-packages.html#micropip), I assume the `micropip.install()` should be linked to a .whl file and not .zip. I used `python3 -m build` to create the .whl file, and then uploaded it to github.

This is the error code:

```
pyodide.asm.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result     raise self._exception   File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 234, in __step     result = coro.throw(exc)   File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 183, in install     transaction = await self.gather_requirements(requirements, ctx, keep_going)   File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 173, in gather_requirements     await gather(*requirement_promises)   File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 284, in __await__     yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.   File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 304, in __wakeup     future.result()   File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result     raise self._exception   File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step     result = coro.send(None)   File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 245, in add_requirement     await self.add_wheel(name, wheel, version, (), ctx, transaction)   File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 313, in add_wheel     with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(wheel_bytes)) as zip_file:   File "/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 1258, in __init__     self._RealGetContents()   File "/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 1325, in _RealGetContents     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

My code looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <p>My first Pyodide app</p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function main() {
        let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
        await pyodide.loadPackage("micropip");
        const micropip = pyodide.pyimport("micropip");
        await micropip.install("url of .whl file");
        await pyodide.runPython(`
        import <package-name>
      `);
      }
      main();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> then uploaded it to github.

The file needs to have [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and correct MIME types set so it could be loaded in the browser on a different domain.  Most likely when opening that URL you are getting some other HTTP response (maybe some error message), which is indeed then not a zip file. You can look at the network tab in the browser dev tools to see the response you are getting.

In general, a good solution is to proxy your file on Github  via [JS Delivr CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/github), as Github is not really designed for this. This will also set CORS headers.